# prove that $2 < [\bar{F} : F] < \infty$ is impossible

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a Field, and $\bar{F}$ be an algebraic closure of $F$

I want to prove that $2 < [\bar{F} : F] < \infty$ is impossible.

For $[\bar{F}:F]=2$, I know there is Artin-Schreire theorem  which characterized this special case and classify such $F$

It seems to me that $[\bar{F} : F]=\infty$ gives $\bar{F} \simeq F^{\infty}$...
How this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the Artin–Schreier theorem:

> If a field $F$ is not algebraically closed but its algebraic closure $C$ is a finite extension of $F$, then $C = F (i)$ with $i^2=-1$.

For a proof, see an [exposition](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/artinschreier.pdf) by Keith Conrad.